# How to change the text of UIButton from ActionSheet

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, uialertaction

I want to change the text of UIButton **city** .

But its not working, can you tell me whats the problem here? And this IBAction **setUpCityDropDown**  is connected to same UIButton.

```
 @IBAction func setUpCityDropDown()
        {
            let ActionSheet =  UIAlertController(title: "Which City?", message: "City Name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

            let cancelActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            }
            let delhiActionActionButton : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delhi", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {   action -> Void in


                self.city.setTitle("Delhi", forState:  UIControlState.Normal)
                self.city.sizeToFit()

            }
            let mumbaiActionActionButton : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Mumbai", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                action -> Void in
                self.city.setTitle("Mumbai", forState:  UIControlState.Normal)

                self.city.sizeToFit()
            }
            let ahmedabadActionButton : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ahmedabad", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                action -> Void in
                self.city.setTitle("Ahmedabad", forState:  UIControlState.Normal)

                self.city.sizeToFit()
            }

            ActionSheet.addAction(cancelActionButton)
            ActionSheet.addAction(ahmedabadActionButton)
            ActionSheet.addAction(delhiActionActionButton)
            ActionSheet.addAction(mumbaiActionActionButton)
            self.presentViewController(ActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you setup title in IB for UIButton, it setting up not as `String`, but as `NSAttributedString`. So you need use `setAttributedTitle(_:forState:)` method to change it instead of `setTitle(_:forState:)`

```
@IBAction func setUpCityDropDown()
{
    let ActionSheet =  UIAlertController(title: "Which City?", message: "City Name", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    let cancelActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action in }
    let delhiActionActionButton : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delhi", style: .Default)
    {   
        action in
        self.city.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "Delhi"), forState: .Normal)
        self.city.sizeToFit()
    }
    let mumbaiActionActionButton : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Mumbai", style: .Default)
    {   
        action in
        self.city.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "Mumbai"), forState: .Normal)
        self.city.sizeToFit()
    }
    let ahmedabadActionButton : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ahmedabad", style: .Default)
    {   
        action in
        self.city.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "Ahmedabad"), forState: .Normal)
        self.city.sizeToFit()
    }
    ActionSheet.addAction(cancelActionButton)
    ActionSheet.addAction(ahmedabadActionButton)
    ActionSheet.addAction(delhiActionActionButton)
    ActionSheet.addAction(mumbaiActionActionButton)
    self.presentViewController(ActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Its still not working. Does it have anything to do with TouchUpInside ?

Comment: Is `city` button outlet connected properly? Try to add `city.setTitle("Test", forState: .Normal)` line in `viewWillAppear` method, will it work?

Comment: No, no matter what I do the text is not getting changed.

Comment: So, we found that the problem is not as described in topic. Its a half of solution at least. Close the topic or add additional question with more code to it. As I think you just forget to set `@IBOutlet weak var city: UIButton!` and connect it to storyboard/xib file

Comment: No. I have connected to an Outlet. Thats not the problem.
And thats the only method I have apart from viewDidLoad.

Comment: make breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` and watch at runtime, if `city` property is nil. Also, add `city.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()` to both metods to check if it have any response on screen

Comment: Haha !! Everything is working, except the setTitle.
Not able to set the title in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear.
Though it is not working from viewDidload, but still Is there any problem, because I am changing the text inside UIAlertAction. Because its a different controller ?

Comment: I think I found solution. Check my code after 5 min

Comment: @KetulPatani check it

Comment: Ya it works.
was **NSAttributedString(string: "Mumbai")** , the problem ?

Comment: @KetulPatani Yes. I wrote description in head of my answer.